# How to filter wordpress posts/post-types by their 'parent'?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im setting up a custom wordpress theme and implemented multiple custom post types: "section", "article" and "entry".
The idea: a section has multiple articles, an article has multiple entries, an entry has multiple posts, each displaying their "childs" as thumbnails in their respective template.

(Example:
a section called "travels" containes two articles: NZ and FR.
a second section called "books" contains "harry potter" and "glennkill")

Thus, the permalinks are supposed to look like this:
*travels/NZ/Day-1/arrival-at-the-airport*
or
*books/harry-potter/philosophers-stone/chapter-1*

This is the loop code for the front page, where all possible sections are displayed:
`

```
    /* define parameter for the query */
    $args = array(
        'post-type'     => 'section',
        'orderby'       =>   'title',
        'order'         =>     'ASC'
    );


    /* define the new query to loop through the parameter just set */
    $custom_query  = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : while ( $custom_query->have_post()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?> Section">
                <div class="section">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                    <p class="front_page_section_title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </a>`
```

and this is the section template code i came up so far:

```
$args = array(
        'post-type'     =>   'article',
        'orderby'        =>      'date',
        'order'            =>     'DESC'
    );


    /* define the new query to loop through*/
    $custom_query  = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : while ( $custom_query->have_post()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <div class="article">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                    <p class="front_page_article_title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </a>
```

So, what does the code for a section template has to look like in order to only loop articles 'child' to the clicked section?
Can the section's loop $args array automaticly set a parameter called "tag" to the section's title and then filter all articles (manually tagged) with the same name? (code for deeper hirarchical elements will be basicly be the same i suppose)

Thanks in advance!
Sorry for any spelling/grammar mistakes.

Comment: why don't you use categories for that?

Comment: Whether im using categories or tags to sort the child elements, i still dont know how to implement either as a function running automaticly in the section template to adjust to the section selected on the front page. 

permalink-wise: if i had nested/hirarchical categories, would the permalink %category%-slug display the links as mentioned?

I'm new to wordpress and just started understanding its inner workings.